# problem with getting error "Unable to resolve dependency"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

}
```

what can i do to resolve this as like in the code, i adjusted the 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0' and so it is ignored

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':slidingMenu@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: slidingMenu
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':slidingMenu@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: slidingMenu
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':slidingMenu@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:``26.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: slidingMenu
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':slidingMenu@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: slidingMenu
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':slidingMenu@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: slidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are changing Gradle's file location defaults (through the use of `sourceSets`) so to resolve this error remove this block of code:

```
...
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
...
```

**NOTE:**

1. Support libraries should be the same version as the `compileSdk` version so instead of
   `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'`
   Use 
   `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`
2. The plugin `android-library` is deprecated. Consider using 
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
   instead of
   `apply plugin: 'android-library'`